# Should text always be enclosed in a html tag?

Tags: html

Say I have an input field and next to it I have text.  Should the text always be enclosed in a html tag?  If so why?

```
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
```

VS

```
<label for="fname">First name:</label> <input type="text" name="fname">
```

Answer (score 5):

Label in this case allows you to click on the label itself - and it will give focus to the input with the id supplied in the `for` attribute. It's recommended for usability.

Just make sure to set the input's `id` that the label's `for` is set to the inputs `id`.

Comment: +1 for you, I have written the same information with example - we were writing simultaneously - it happens :(

Comment: Yes, though your answer points out that he's lacking id so +1 reciprocated.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely this way:

```
<label for="fname">First name:</label> <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
```

The browser understands the connection between `for` attribute of `label` and `id` attribute of `input`.
The result is (for example), you can click the `label` and coresponding `input` gets focus.

Answer (score 1):

To make a story short, yes you should. An unenclosed text is not very far from an image. It is hardly accessible and barely alterable without replacing it completely.

For css rules, it is much easier if you can easily get a grip around each element groups of the document, including the text.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness sake:

```
<label>First name: <input type="text" name="fname"></label>
```

is possible too; more seen with `type="radio"`.

As said: clickable (nice for check boxes and radio buttons), and for screen readers for the visually impaired: can read out loud the label while coming in the text box with tab.

For the other label form I have seen JavaScript validation, marking the label (on error).